# How does one show that if $\gamma < b^r$ then $\gamma$ is not an upper bound of all $b^t$ s.t. $t\leq r$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

I was doing exericise 6c) from Rudin and I had 3 proof strategies that should work however, one seems ridiculously simpler than the others (plus the others seem very interesting so I would love to see hints/solutions to them!).

So what I am trying to prove is that 
$$b^r = sup B(r) = \sup \{ b^t \mid t \in \mathbb Q \leq r \}$$

where $r \in \mathbb Q$

I am stuck showing the least upper bound property (LUB). So what I need to show is:

$$ \text{if } \gamma < b^r \implies \exists b^{t'} \in B(r) : \gamma \leq b^{t'}$$

so I just need to show there is some element $\gamma$ doesn't upper bound. To show that there are 3 strategies I thought of:

1) Consider $b^{r - \frac{1}{n}}$. Then there exists some sufficiently large $n \in \mathbb Q$ (or $\mathbb N$) such that $ \gamma < b^{r - \frac{1}{n}} < b^r$. Equivalently its obviously true (but not obvious to actually prove at least not to me) that $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} b^{r -\frac{1}{n}} = b^r \implies \exists b^{t'}$ s.t. $\gamma \leq b^{t'}$. Essentially the intuition is that since $\gamma$ is fixed but our exponents are not we can just be really close to $b^r$ to satisfy the condition we need.

2) Another strategy is that to show $\gamma$ can be written as $\gamma = b^k$ for some $k$. That would show that $\gamma = b^k < b^r \implies k<r$ since $b>1$ then there must exists some $r=r-\epsilon$ so $b^{r-\epsilon} = b^{r}b^{-\epsilon} < b^r$. Which seems to conclude the proof but I don't know how to show $\forall \gamma \mathbb R_{>1}, \exists ! k \in \mathbb Q: b^k = \gamma$. So if I find $k$ then I can just define an upper bound for $\gamma$ with the usual average trick: $\tilde t = \frac{k+r}{2}$. Then I would show $b^k < b^{\tilde t} < b^r$ which is clear because $k < \tilde t < r$.

3) Last but not least, in a brute force way to prove the implication lets use the contrapositive because why not. So we have:

$$ \text{if } \forall b^{t'} \in B(r): \gamma > b^{t'} \implies \gamma b^r $$

which actually (unsatisfactory) seems trivial to proof (which makes me think my proof is wrong, and even if its not, the others seem a lot more interesting cuz they give insights to logarithms and exponentials). Essentially the proof is to note that because of the definition of $B(r)$ we have that we can just choose $t'=r$. Then because of the definition of $B(r)$ is inclusive $\leq$ (which my intuition tells me that if it were exclusive $t<r$) the theorem from rudin 6c) should still be true) then we have $b^t = b^r \in B(r)$. But we assumed $\gamma$ is strictly larger than all elements of $B(r)$ which includes this one $b^r$. This we know now that $\gamma < b^r \implies \gamma \leq b^r $ (since the OR less than part of the inequality is true, i.e only one has to be true).

But it feels 3) was too trivial and the $b^r$ should still be a supremum even if $t \leq r$ was changed to $t<r$. Is that true? Also, any hints for the other two proofs that seem a lot more insightful or the a way to show them? In the end it seems that the main issue is that we have $\gamma$ and we need to somehow talk about the exponent $k$ that raised to the $b$ is $\gamma$. That seems to be the crux, to move to the exponent land. Any hints?

Comment: There is perhaps a typo. You want to have $b^{r} =\sup\, \{b^{t} \mid t\in\mathbb{Q}, t\leq r\} $. Also if $r$ is irrational then this is one of the definitions of $b^r$ and there is nothing to prove here. If $r$ is rational then you can do this with some algebraic manipulation.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh yes the $\in \mathbb Q$ was on the wrong place, oops!

Comment: Just to confirm : is $r$ rational or irrational?

Comment: @ParamanandSingh definitively $r$ is rational. I will include that (forgotten) detail.

Comment: Ok I see another issue here which is perhaps a typo. We should have $t<r$ and not $t\leq r$. The problem is trivial if $t\leq r$ because we can always choose $t=r$ and then $b^{t} >\gamma$ so that $b^{r} $ is the desired supremum.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh that one isn't a typo and you can check in Rudin (page 22 in my book). That is what my point 3 points out in my question (that is seems weirdly trivial).

Comment: I am only saying that the problem is trivial if $t\leq r$ and requires effort only when change it to $t<r$. In fact you can prove that the supremum is same weather we use $t<r$ or $t\leq r$. Anyway as I had remarked earlier Rudin has the habit of presenting trivial things in complicated manner. Let me know if you need proof for the case when $t<r$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh how is it trivial in your view? (just so I can compare your reasoning with mine, thanks for your patience and help :) )

Comment: First using your previous question we can see that $b^{r} $ is an upper bound for the given set. To see that it is least upper bound take any number $\gamma<b^{r} $ and then we have a member $b^{r} $ of this set which is greater than $\gamma$ so $b^{r} $ is least upper bound. Note the if a set a has a maximum, then trivially it is the least upper bound of that set. The power of supremum comes when the set has no maximum. Changing the inequality to $t<r$ ensures that the set has no maximum and then problem is not trivial but again it is a matter of algebraic manipulation of inequalities.

Comment: How did you actually *prove* that this element $b^k$ from $B(r)$ is greater than $\gamma < b^k< b^r$? (thanks for your patience, yes I agree with the maximum comment)

Comment: Also you should see that when $r$ is irrational then the case $t=r$ will never occur and hence the definition of $b^{r} $ as a supremum makes perfect sense.

Comment: Well you take $\gamma<b^{r} $ and hence $b^{r} $ is an element of the set which is greater than $\gamma$. This is what makes it trivial.

Comment: When you are reading a book like Rudin which focuses so much on symbolism / formalism then you need to understand that behind all that symbolism there is very little amount of meaning/understanding and most of it  is trivial.

Comment: And I can see your confusion. We need a member of set greater than $\gamma$. We don't necessarily need a member less than $b^r$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh yea, thats my confusion! It needs to be in $B(r)$, essentially reasoning about exponent (i.e taking logs without saying thats what we are really doing is the key). But I totally agree, sometimes its easy to lose the big picture. I try very hard not to lose it to the best of my abilities, thanks for the reminder :)

Comment: You should by the way try to consider this problem with $t<r$ also. That would give you some opportunities to exercise your abilities. And I will provide any help if necessary.